# filter results to show matching results with ng-show angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I can filter results with the below where all entries appear on the page

```
    <body ng-app="">
        <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                               {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                               {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                               {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                               {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                               {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

      Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
      <table id="searchTextResults">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
          <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
          <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a jquery UI autocomplete type solution where there is nothing on the page initially but as you type the matching entries appear.

I thought I might be able to do this with ng-show, so far I can only do for example

```
ng-show="searchText == 'John'"
```

which means it will always be blank unless you type in John.
Is there a way with ng-show or ng-if to filter (show matching entries) as you type like the filter does?
I have the below demonstrating my John example

```
    <body ng-app="">
        <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                               {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                               {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                               {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                               {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                               {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

      Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
      <table id="searchTextResults">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText" ng-show="searchText == 'John'">
          <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
          <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
```

I also tried

```
        ng-show="searchText == searchText"
```

but this just shows all items?
Can this be done with ng-show? 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a custom filter. It can be done very easily. This filter will test the name of your friend against the search. If

```
app.filter('filterFriends', function() {
    return function(friends, search) {
        if (search === "") return friends;
        return friends.filter(function(friend) {
           return friend.name.match(search); 
        });
    }
});
```

This should give you a good idea of how to create filters, and you can customize it as you like. In your HTML you would use it like this.

```
<input ng-model="search">
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filterFriends:search">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/dxzfku44/).

Comment: You've not defined the `list` variable anywhere. Could just replace it with `[]`.

Comment: It was supposed to say 'friends'. I renamed the variable and missed that one. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to just do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-show="([friend] | filter:search).length > 0">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also this way the filter will apply to all the properties, not just name.